# Changing focus of a dynamic list in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a function in flutter that opens a dialogue box with a list of text fields. The size of the list is determined by an argument to the function. I want to move focus to the next item as each is entered. I have tried creating a list of focus nodes to do this, but it doesn't work. Can someone point out what I am doing wrong. The code I have is shown below.

```
Future<bool> getPositions(BuildContext context, List<String> positions) async
{
  int numPositions = positions.length ;
  final List<FocusNode> _fNodes = new List<FocusNode>.generate(numPositions, (_) => new FocusNode()) ;
  List<Widget> _widgets = new List<Widget>(numPositions) ;

  for (int i = 0 ; i < numPositions ; ++i)
  {
    int p = i+1;
    _widgets[i] = new TextField(
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0),
          autofocus: true,
          focusNode: _fNodes[i],
          controller: TextEditingController(text: positions[i]),
          textInputAction: p < numPositions ? TextInputAction.next : TextInputAction.done,
          onChanged: (value)
          {
            if (value.trim().isNotEmpty)
              positions[i] = value.trim();
          },
          onSubmitted: (value)
          {
            if (value.trim().isNotEmpty)
              positions[i] = value.trim();
            if (p >= numPositions)
              Navigator.pop(context, true);
            else
              _fieldFocusChange(context, _fNodes[i], _fNodes[p]);
          },
    );
  }

  return showDialog<bool>(
    context: context,
    barrierDismissible: false,
    builder: (context)
    {
      return AlertDialog(
        title: Text("${Config.position} names", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0)),
        titlePadding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
        content: new Container(
          width: double.maxFinite,
          height: 300.0,
          child: ListView(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            children: _widgets,
          ),
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[
          new FlatButton(
              child: const Text('CANCEL'),
              onPressed: ()
              {
                Navigator.of(context).pop(false);
              }),
          new FlatButton(
              child: const Text("OK"),
              onPressed: ()
              {
                Navigator.of(context).pop(true);
              }),
        ],
      );
    },
  );
}

void _fieldFocusChange(BuildContext context, FocusNode currentFocus,FocusNode nextFocus)
{
  currentFocus.unfocus();
  FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(nextFocus);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest adding `autofocus: i == 0`, else every node is requesting focus on build.

**Minimal Viable Example:**

```
class Test extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    int listLength = 4;
    List<FocusNode> _focusNodes = List<FocusNode>.generate(listLength, (int index) => FocusNode());

    List<Widget> textFields = List<Widget>.generate(listLength, (int index) => TextField(
      controller: TextEditingController(),
      focusNode: _focusNodes[index],
      onSubmitted: (String value){
        if (index < listLength){
          _focusNodes[index+1].requestFocus();
        }
      },
    ));

    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: ListView(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            children: textFields
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Changing the autoFocus made no difference. But my focusNode didn't have a requestFocus method. Updating flutter fixed this and now the focus change seems to work. I guess there was a bug.

Comment: This is not dynamic since you specifically set a listLength.

Comment: „The size of the list is determined by an argument to the function“